How to get BuildConfig.VERSION in a kmm project without expect/actual?
I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile (KMM) project and I need to access the version of the project, without using the expect/actual mechanism.
On Android, we can easily retrieve the version using BuildConfig.VERSION, but this is only available for Java or Android-specific code. Since I need a solution that works across all platforms (Android and iOS), I’m looking for an alternative approach to access the version in the common code. What would be the best way to handle this in a KMM project without relying on platform-specific code?

BuildKonfig https://github.com/yshrsmz/BuildKonfig
